# R Histogram over discrete variable - Two of the bins stick

Tags: r, ggplot2

So, I'm trying to plot a histogram over a dataframe -> y for the column -> ProsperRating..numeric. (There is a period at the end of the variable name).

So , this is what I've got so far. (After overlaying normal curve).

```
h <- hist(y$ProsperRating..numeric.,breaks = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)) 
xfit <- seq(min(y$ProsperRating..numeric.) , max(y$ProsperRating..numeric.) , length = nrow(y))
yfit <- dnorm(xfit, mean = mean(y$ProsperRating..numeric.), sd = sd(y$ProsperRating..numeric.))
yfit <- yfit * length(y$ProsperRating..numeric.) *diff(h$mids[1:2]) * 1.8 
lines(xfit,yfit,lwd = 2)
```

[Histogram plot - Notice 1 and 2 numbered bins sticking together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKeNo.png)

Is there any other way I could do this too ? Total noob to R.

Edit 1 : Prosper rating numeric is a column in my dataframe . It contains the value 1-7 in increments on 1 (`x = seq(1,7,1)`). That is what I'm trying to plot here.

Edit 2 : Adding the new normal curve. Changed code to reflect breaks.
[New Normal Curve!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3Uug.png)
No clue if this is done right.

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: I don't need the first two bins to stick like in the image. Other than that it is fine(I guess)

Comment: add some reproducible data, e.g. using `dput(your_data)`

Comment: @Jimbou I've added info about the data!

Comment: Ok, I believe there is a problem with the breaks. You can try to use `breaks = seq(0, 8, 0.5)` instead of `breaks = 10`.

Comment: Here is a way to replicate the data  `x <- c(rep(1,8000),rep(2,10000),rep(3,15000), rep(4, 20000), rep(5, 15500), rep(6, 14500), rep(7, 5000))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaks is only a suggestion.

```
set.seed(1337)
hist(runif(20,1,10), breaks = 3) # only shows two bins
```

The only way to explicit control the bin size, assuming that will correct you graph. Is to set breaks to a vector of x-axis break locations.

```
set.seed(1337)
hist(rnorm(20), breaks = c(-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3))
```

That being said the bins are 'sticking together' because that is exactly how it should look. There is close to 1000 observed values between 1.5 and 2. You could separate them by adding a bin where data doesn't exist between them or, without looking at your data, adding a bin from 0 to 1 might fix the visual issue `breaks = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)`.

I suggest doing this.

```
x <- c(rep(1,8000),rep(2,10000),rep(3,15000), rep(4, 20000), rep(5, 15500), rep(6, 14500), rep(7, 5000))
hist(x, breaks = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7))
```

Gets rid of the spaces all together which I think is much better to look at anyway.

Comment: Hey @Matt L. That worked great. Thank you very much. Can you tell me if the normal curve looks correct ? I have a feeling it is not correct for the given plot. Thanks!

Comment: @WhatIfTheyGetMe It looks correct. You might want to fit a t-distribution instead of a normal. The t has thicker tails and I think it would fit your data better. To fix the limits on the new graph you can do `ylim = c(0,20000)` inside the hist function.